# Reverse engineer VFD control signal from schematic

Tags: analog, pwm, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

There's a TLDR at the bottom!

I got a brushless DC motor and VFD from an old treadmill, both are Baldor brand. Unfortunately it looks like they were made by Baldor specifically for this treadmill, and no separate documentation is available for them. It's a Burdick T600 treadmill, and I also got the main "brain" board from the treadmill, although I have reason to believe something may be wrong with it.

My goal here is to use the motor and VFD for another project (not to fix the treadmill). So I want to speak directly to the VFD and eliminate the treadmill mainboard.

I followed the instructions in the service manual for the treadmill to put the treadmill main board into "test mode," where I can run the motor easily. Initially, when I commanded it to start the motor, it ran back and forth about 1 time a second. I started playing with things, and I found out that if I don't allow the speed control signal to get from the treadmill main board to the VFD, but I allow the start/stop/power lines to work as normal, the VFD spins the motor up to max speed (4000rpm) no problem. So if the VFD sees an open circuit across the two speed control lines, it seems to interpret that as max speed.

Reading between the lines in the service manual, it sounds like maybe the VFD is expecting to see a variable resistance between the two speed control lines. If I leave the lines open and measure the voltage across them coming from the VFD, I get about 15VDC.

I have the schematic from the treadmill main board, and this is the section that is responsible for the speed control lines.

[image]

The service manual seems to imply that there is a PWM signal driving the optocoupler, but no idea on the specifics of that signal. I don't have a scope handy right now, it'll be 4-5 days before I can get access to one, or I'd just check.

TLDR: Is this optocoupler-in-parallel-with-a-resistor arrangement a pretty typical way to make a digitally controlled variable resistance? And if so, what value of potentiometer should I use to mimic this? (I want manual control over VFD speed.)

Answer (score 0):

The 5k has no advantage and needs a pullup to make a logic level. I suggest 1k.

But perhaps it is used as an emitter follower for better speed. [Then you need  a pull-down resistor and Vcc to collector.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDCAcB0CMBMBWApgWgJwlma8xngHZCBmMSeANnXUJABYSsJ74QVVZYAoAJxCSUslCIKzxI4dvjDcASgMRCEksZAgaGEEtCaaciPlgTjJsevVNSSiQtwDmi5ejZj48Sxu4B5AZDMiICQkyoFe9GB05pYqWITKEljcEUw2bOhC9OrCmvQA%20pT5YHn0iCTmeTqwiIjw6ASklJTYpHk4MrBteTyO0TlYFlguUvDyxmyx2bGWiFoyQVIacIjo1fTojGAuyWBMhUF4Q2wkkJ4CBUXdjM2EbdAdd-iUkJTxz0%20QtmToXfB5fyQjGJYIFgcMWIRZCkQPsPBBYMMyGdIBcuoxEPlEHdOsU-ijAQB3Jz9CQBLxEuEkpT9WQUiJWYGJKG7IK1OKZbKU%20H5QpdBAYrHtfA4%205gV7odTqZ7oRDYfB-XFXSrcE5QRbsEAAWQAhgAPAA6AGcAGoAewANgAXbX2ZDcIA)

Answer (score 0):

The VFD is most likely driven in current by a PWM (as stated in the manual).

One can guess that the VFD has a filter that allows going from a PWM current-driven signal to a voltage or filtered current draw, ultimately converting the signal to a voltage level.

The 5k resistor allows tuning the minimum average current draw to have the speed range from 0 to max speed.

It's very typical to have a motor speed controller controlled by a PWM signal and it's also typical to use an optocoupler to isolate a PWM signal.

If you want a quick fix, most likely a potentiometer between JP5 pins would allow you to control the speed, or at least test that the motor drive works properly. Note that you would lose the isolation so some attention is required.

Your question doesn't specify what you are trying to achieve. Is the treadmill broken, are you trying to hack it by reusing part for another project?

> "test mode," where I can run the motor easily. Initially, when I
> commanded it to start the motor, it ran back and forth about 1 time a
> second.

Note that this could be a normal test sequence. Else, checking the connectors between the boards and also the control panel for bad contact, corroded contact, etc would probably be the place to start.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I should've clarified, I'm trying to hack this motor and VFD to use in another project. I have no interest in the treadmill itself and I want to eliminate the need for the treadmill mainboard and deal directly with the VFD. How would you suggest choosing a potentiometer? I don't want to fry anything by allowing too much current draw, which is why I haven't tried just shorting it to see if that results in the slowest possible speed.

Comment: Given the implementation, it should be safe to short it as the optocoupler has the potential to short it (100% PWM). If you just want to have a simple solution, try the potentiometer. I would suggest trying with a 5k potentiometer and remove the 5k resistor. Better would be to use the same optocoupler and feed it with a PWM from an Arduino, 5-20khz is a typical frequency.